Create Wavy/Curvy Path with Nodes in Flutter
I want to create a screen with a kind of a curvy path with nodes on the path as shown in the image of the design. I know I need to use CustomPainter and its quadraticBezierTo method for this and use Stack to place the nodes on it. However I am facing issue with creating this wavy pattern as it is not exactly following a sine-like curve and is a bit random if you see the image closely. Also for the nodes, I need to follow the guidelines :

Be positioned randomly on the horizontal axis (avoid manually
entering the node coordinates)
Maintain equal vertical spacing
Persist their positions across app restarts

Persistence thing can be achieved using Caching once I figure out how to place the nodes. So can anyone help we with how to create this wavy pattern and how to place the nodes ?

till now I have tried this but it is not giving the desired output
class CurvyRoadmapPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final int numberOfNodes;
  final int currentNodeIndex;
  final double animationValue;
  final Function(List<Offset>) onPositionsCalculated;
  final List<Offset> nodePositions = [];

  CurvyRoadmapPainter(
    this.numberOfNodes,
    this.currentNodeIndex,
    this.animationValue,
    this.onPositionsCalculated,
  );

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 5;

    nodePositions.clear();
    final path = Path();
    final segmentHeight = size.height / (numberOfNodes - 1);
    final ydiff = size.height / 5;

    // Starting point (centered at top)
    double startX = size.width * 0.75;
    path.moveTo(startX, 0);
    nodePositions.add(Offset(startX, 0));
    
    for (int i = 1; i < numberOfNodes; i++) {
      final prevY = (i - 1) * segmentHeight;
      final currentY = i * segmentHeight;
      
      final controlX = i.isEven ? size.width * 1.4 : -size.width * 0.4;
      
      final endX = size.width * 0.5;

      path.quadraticBezierTo(
        controlX,
        (prevY + currentY) / 2, // Control point Y remains halfway between nodes
        endX,
        currentY,
      );

      nodePositions.add(Offset(endX, currentY));
    }

    // Draw background path
    paint.color = Colors.white.withOpacity(0.3);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

    // Draw completed path
    if (currentNodeIndex > 0) {
      final completedPath = Path();
      var prevPos = nodePositions[0];

      for (int i = 1; i <= currentNodeIndex; i++) {
        final currentPos = nodePositions[i];
        final controlX = i.isEven ? size.width * 1.4 : -size.width * 0.4;

        completedPath.moveTo(prevPos.dx, prevPos.dy);
        completedPath.quadraticBezierTo(
          controlX,
          (prevPos.dy + currentPos.dy) / 2,
          currentPos.dx,
          currentPos.dy,
        );

        prevPos = currentPos;
      }

      // Animate current segment
      if (currentNodeIndex < numberOfNodes - 1) {
        final nextPos = nodePositions[currentNodeIndex + 1];
        final controlX = (currentNodeIndex + 1).isEven
            ? size.width * 1.4
            : -size.width * 0.4;

        completedPath.moveTo(prevPos.dx, prevPos.dy);
        completedPath.quadraticBezierTo(
          controlX,
          (prevPos.dy + nextPos.dy) / 2,
          lerp(prevPos.dx, nextPos.dx, animationValue),
          lerp(prevPos.dy, nextPos.dy, animationValue),
        );
      }

      paint.color = Colors.green;
      canvas.drawPath(completedPath, paint);
    }

    onPositionsCalculated(nodePositions);
  }

  double lerp(double a, double b, double t) {
    return a + (b - a) * t;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CurvyRoadmapPainter oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate.currentNodeIndex != currentNodeIndex ||
        oldDelegate.animationValue != animationValue;
  }
}


please add the code that you have tried so far!

actually cubitTo is better in that case

have added the code i have tried so far !

check this gist that contains getSmoothPath function - it uses a series of Path.cubicTo method calls to form a smooth path
